# Application that runs from eclipse on device doesn't run on device alone, what can I do?

Tags: android, device

I build some application that collects info about the battery. when I try to run it using eclipse with debugging mode with the android device (not emulator) it works fine even when I just hit Run. When I install it on the device (the apk file) I can't run it...
Another strange thing when I install it the open button is disabled.

what can I do to determine what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have signed the application or not?have you disabled the debug mode in AndroidManifest.xml file by setting its value to "false"?